# Firefox jQuery Drag and Drop File Upload together with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop

I am after a jQuery/PHP means of allowing a user to drag and drop files and then via PHP, upload one or more files to a specific directory on a Linux box.

I only have Firefox 3.6 as my base browser but can also move to FFox if need be.

Can use any HTML5 features as long as I'm using Firefox 3.6

Can someone possibly point me to any examples/sites where this process is demonstrated?

I have had a look at http://www.plupload.com/index.php but this does not work in IE6.

As mentioned, would like it to work in FFox only.

Comment: Why do you need this on IE 6???

Comment: Unfortunately where I work, the SOE is IE6 but sounds like I will be using FireFox 3.6 instead. Unfortunately though, Plupload does not seem to work in FFox?

Comment: http://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers._

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a solution that does this on *IE 6*  is really, really building a stall for a dead horse IMO.

It *may* perhaps be possible using some proprietary - and likely commercial - ActiveX or Java plug-in - I'm not sure. But why go through that, when native support is around the corner in HTML 5?

Firefox 3.6 is the one browser that at the moment provides best support for it, so I would recommend to target that for the moment, and other browsers as they catch up in functionality... Whatever you do, I would really not waste time trying to get stuff like this working in IE 6 except if there is a really, really compelling reason why that specific browser *has* to be supported.

Comment: Hi Pekka, do you or anybody else know of any solutions for my requriement that will work in Firefox 3.6?

Comment: @tonsils take a look at this: http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload should be a basis to start with.